# Getting "There was a parsing the package" error while installing the package.

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a apk in unknown source and im trying to install it over various of devices. The same apk i can install it in one device but on another device of same version and make it couldn't be done. i have disable all the security for unkown source installation. whenever im trying to install it over devices im getting "There was a problem parsing the package". I have checked below basic checklist for this issue.

-> APK downloaded properly
-> Device has exact version of the apk 
-> Enabled the unknown source installation.

Can anyone guide me what could be the problem for installation. How come to get the root-cause.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Your Android OS version might be the same but what about other dependencies such as

1. Google Play Service version
2. One device being rooted and the other is not
3. [Device Compatibility](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/compatibility.html) and permissions

etc?

When you are trying to install via adb, you will get a INSTALL ERROR code. Please print that as well.

If all else fails, factory reset the other device and hopefully that should work.